# Moment js skipping month in react with redux

Tags: reactjs, redux, momentjs

I'm building a sort of a calendar webpage and I'm using react with Redux as state management. To deal with dates and time, I'm using MomentJs. I want to flip through the different months of the year, which has been implemented fairly well. I've now spotted a problem. When I try to go to March in any year, it is skipped and April is showing. Another thing is I can only go back to February of any year. All other months works fine which is really odd. I've used the momentjs docs to figure out what is wrong, but can't seem to figure it out. So, my component where the action is called:

**Component**

```
...
handleChangeCalendarStateClick = type => {
            switch (this.props.calendarType) {
                case "month":
                    if (type === "next") {
                        //this.props.changeCalendarStateTest("next");   
                        let month = this.props.calendarState.add(1, "M").format("YYYY/MM/DD");            
                        this.props.changeCalendarState(month);
                    } else {
                        let month = this.props.calendarState.subtract(1, "M").format("YYYY/MM/DD"); 
                        this.props.changeCalendarState(month);
                        //this.props.changeCalendarStateTest("prev");
                    }
                    break;
                case "week":
                    if (type === "next") {
                        console.log(this.props.calendarState);
                        this.props.changeCalendarState(this.props.calendarState.add(1, "w"));
                    } else {
                        this.props.changeCalendarState(this.props.calendarState.subtract(1, "w"));
                    }
                    break;
                case "day":
                    if (type === "next") {
                        this.props.changeCalendarState(this.props.calendarState.add(1, "d"));
                    } else {
                        this.props.changeCalendarState(this.props.calendarState.subtract(1, "d"));
                    }
                    break;
                default:
                    break;

            }
        }
 ...
```

**Action**

```
...
export const changeCalendarStateAction = state => { 
    return {
        type: changeCalendarState, payload: { "state": state }
    }
}
...
```

**Reducer**

```
const initialState = {
...
calendarState: moment(),
...
}
...
case changeCalendarState: {
        return {
            ...state,
            calendarState: moment(action.payload.state)
        }
    }
...
```

Now comes the really odd part, this action/reducer works for `Week` and for `Day` views. (Like in the google calendar). In those views, the navigation to March and past February works as it should. It is only in the `Month` view it does not.

Comment: I have a feeling its a similar reason to this: https://github.com/moment/moment/issues/754 . If you go from April to March , does it work ? Or does it skips March and goes to February ?

Comment: Hm, that works, but then it stops at February and doesn't go any further back, it just stays at February.

Comment: Try using `this.props.calendarState.day(1)` every where , I suspect there's a problem with `Feb` because it only has 28 days. Try always using the first of the month .

Comment: Unfortunately did not solve anything. It now just skippes April, and not luck getting past February.

Comment: @Lasse What is ```this.props.calendarState``` is it a moment obj?

Comment: @Win yes just a plain old moment object. See the "Reducer", inside of initialState

Comment: @Lasse I tried your code exactly and the dates seems to be moving around just fine... Are you just displaying the dates? Is there a chance of an issue in something that isn't in your post? Maybe if you are putting it in a calendar then the calendar is having the issue handling the moment date.

Comment: @ageoff Hm, well.. It's a custom build, where I've build everything from the ground up, so it must be something somewhere that is broken.. I just tried it on an older deployment, and there it works just fine. Might be something in the env or something. Have to give it a look and compare versions. But to answer your question, I use moment to display the  year/month/day in the calendar.

Comment: @Lasse `I use moment to display the year/month/day in the calendar` I would say check that (maybe add to your post). The moment library seems to handle the date fine, so I would say the breakdown is in how it is displayed. Again, just a guess since the code seemed to work fine when I gave it a shot (and just printed in console the date).